# What is the best way to create a tableA HABTM tableA relationship for a CakePHP application?

Tags: php, database-design, cakephp

I have the need to create the functionality to allow my registered users to associate themselves with other uses and create a family. My database tables look something like this:

**db.persons** - (Bob, Jane, Timmy, etc)

- id
- name
- email

**db.persons_persons**

- id
- person__id_parent
- person_id_child
- relationtype_id

**db.relationtypes** - (spouse, child, nephew, etc)

- id
- name

With this structure, I should be able to specify that Bob is a Spouse of Jane in the persons_persons table. The record in db.persons_persons would look something like (psuedo):

```
ID | person_parent | person_child | relationtype
1  | Bob           | Jane         | Spouse
2  | Bob           | Timmy        | Child
```

I realize this could cause some data fragmentation since if Bob and Jane are married, then a child of one would have to be associated with the other. However that is not my question. My question is whether or not this database setup is 'most-correct' for use in a cakePHP application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, CakePHP will automatigally inflect a `people` table into a `people` controller and a `person` model, so you don't need to call it `persons`. Then I'd call the lookup table `relationships` rather than `persons_persons`.

I'd call the fields in your relationships table `person_id`, `relation_id` and `relation_type_id`, and then add an underscore in your `relationtypes` table name so it becomes `relation_types`.

I think this is more semantic.

You could still use a hasAndBelongsToMany association, and make use of the automagic "[with](http://www.cricava.com/blogs/index.php?blog=6&title=modelizing_habtm_join_tables_in_cakephp_&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1)" associations offered by CakePHP (1.2 only) to access the additional data in the HABTM table for relation type.

However, I'd be tempted to use:

- `Person` hasMany `Relation`
- `Relation` belongsTo `Person`, `Relation`, `RelationType`

In your app, is a persons relationship implied by someone else's relationship to them? I.e. if you find Person.id = 1 you might get all their relations, e.g. Person.id 2, 3 and 4. But if you find Person.id 2, you would not automatically get Person.id = 1, unless there was another record in the relations table that represented that relationship.

To achieve this, you can set up another assocation:

- `Person` hasMany `Relation1` with foreignKey `person_id`
- `Person` hasMany `Relation2` with foreignKey `relation_id`
- `Relation` belongsTo `Person`, `Relation`, `RelationType`

Note, you can achieve this dual relationship with HABTM too.

Comment: This exactly the kind of advice I was looking for. Very clear, insightful, and beneficial. Much thanks.